# Example react-virtualized html page using CDN

Tags: react-virtualized

I am unable to understand that how to use react-virtualized components like AutoSizer . Can anyone share react-virtualized CDN example . I am trying to create react page using CDN link.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of usable examples on [Demo page](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List)
It's possible to find source for examples with `AutoSizer` component. If you want to resize `List` dimension just use value which is supplied by `AutoSizer`.

```
      <AutoSizer disableHeight>
        {({width}) => (
          <List
            ref="List"
            className={styles.List}
            height={listHeight}
            overscanRowCount={overscanRowCount}
            noRowsRenderer={this._noRowsRenderer}
            rowCount={rowCount}
            rowHeight={
              useDynamicRowHeight ? this._getRowHeight : listRowHeight
            }
            rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
            scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
            width={width}
          />
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
```

Additionally `react-virtualized` provides [docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/) for each component.